# Logistic Regression with 2 Binary Variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I'm working with a data set related to ADHD.

I have 2 columns.

One is ADHD_Control_Croup, where 1 means that the person suffers from, ADHD and 2 means that the person is part of a Control Group. I changed these to 0 an 1, respectively, and made sure they were as.factor.

The second one is `HrsSleep_Use`, where 0 means that the person does not suffer from Insufficiency sleep and 1 means he does suffer.

When trying to draw it with `ggplot` and `geom_smooth`, I'm not seeing the logistic regression line as expected, which is curvy. Also, I'm not seeing my Jitter dots distributed as desired, like linear regressions: some of them in the top left, and the other lines in the bottom right.

Here is the code for the graph:

```r
ggplot(final_sleep_data, aes(x=ADHD_Control_Group, y=HrsSleep_Use)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_smooth(method="glm",
              method.args = list(family="binomial"),
              se = FALSE)
```

This is what I'm seeing as a result:

[image: Jitter]

This is what I would expect:

[image: Expect]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here are the CSV Files and R Code:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FH15vL-NIXUExrJnuhm2Dqv3GbTRdVnj

Here is the

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of `dput(final_sleep_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(final_sleep_data, 20))`.

Comment: try converting your predictor/independent variable `ADHD_Control_Group` so it is numeric and *not* a factor (doesn't matter if it's 0/1 or 1/2)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added the CSV files and R Code. Thanks!

Comment: If you have two binary variables, why do a logistic regression rather than, say, Chi Square or Fisher test? Does a smooth curve between 0 and 1 _mean_ anything? What would the probability at x = 0.5 or x = 0.75 mean if the variable can only take a value of 0 or 1? Would it not be better to plot point estimates and error bars at x = 0 and x = 1?

Answer (score 4):

The plot that you were expecting illustrates a logistic regression with a *continuous* predictor variable and and binary outcome variable. In the data you provided, your predictor variable is a *binary* variable (ADHD control group). A sigmoid curve wouldn't make any sense here, because a sigmoid would show the probability of all the values between 0 and 1. There is no such group as ADHD control group 0.5 or 0.32 or 0.95, yet these values would all be represented in a continuous sigmoid curve.

It makes more sense here to show the probability estimates in the two groups with 95% confidence intervals of those predictions. We can do this as follows:

```r
mod <- glm(HrsSleep_Use ~ ADHD_Control_Group, data = final_sleep_data, 
           family = binomial)

pred_df <- data.frame(ADHD_Control_Group = c(0, 1))

preds <- predict(mod, newdata = pred_df, se.fit = TRUE)

pred_df$HrsSleep_Use <- exp(preds$fit)/(1 + exp(preds$fit))
pred_df$upper <- exp(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit)/
                 (1 + exp(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit))
pred_df$lower <- exp(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit)/
                 (1 + exp(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit))

ggplot(pred_df, aes(factor(ADHD_Control_Group), HrsSleep_Use)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), color = "deepskyblue4",
                linewidth = 3, width = 0.2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous("Percent sleep problems", 
                     labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_discrete("ADHD Control Group") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that your model is more appropriate, although the statistical results (coefficient estimates, p-value, etc.) would all be the same if the predictor were treated as continuous ...

Comment: @BenBolker sure. The model itself is the same either way, but its graphical representation should be different. As it happens, I did try a continuous version, and the probabilities are so close together that it essentially produces a straight line - fairly mystifying as a representation of the model.

Comment: This is great. You could also make use of the `plogis` function provided in base R instead of doing the manual calculations. `with(preds, plogis(fit + se.fit %o% qnorm(c(0.025,0.975))))`